# Regex works on RegExpr but not in Javascript. Matching between underscore and right before a forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match all the stuff between an underscore _ and a backslash . So anything that's like `bahbah_12345_12345\bahbah` I want just the part that's `_12345_12345`.

I used `regexr` and `regex101` to help me build what I want and looks like it works on, but when I put the same string and regular expression in my JS code it finds nothing.

For example here's my regex and sample string

Regex

```
_(.*?)(?=\\)
```

Sample String

```
IShouldGet3Match,allTheSequenceBetweenaUnderScoreAndASlashHeresOne:_1234_1234\andheresAnother_1234_1234_1234\OhLookAnotherOne!_123_12_1234567\bahbahba
```

On regex I get 3 matches, looks good. Then I put it in JS code and the regex doesn't match anything.

```
var pattern = /_(.*?)(?=\\)/g;
var result = str.match(pattern);
```

Here's the [regexr](http://regexr.com/3c716) and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rzLhn6v/).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: If you print the source string, you'll see there are no backslashes in it.  You forgot to escape the backslashes in the string literal, so `\a` is treated as a Bel character, `\b` becomes a backspace, and `\O` is just `O`.

Comment: [Check This](https://jsfiddle.net/3rzLhn6v/2/)

Comment: Ohhh I get it now... feels convoluted to edit the string to escape all the backslash just to get my regex to work. I guess in cases like these you would just have to avoid looking using the backslash as part of your regex and build it some other way?

Comment: If I could offer an optimization to using `.*?`, try this: `_([^\\]*)(?=\\)`  It will look for all characters after a `_` until it hits the backslash. If you think you will encounter newlines that you wish to avoid, you can always add that to the character group: `_([^\n\\]*)(?=\\)` [example 1](https://regex101.com/r/eM9wD0/1). This takes 73 steps to find 9 matches. Otherwise, `.*?` will take 937 steps [example 2](https://regex101.com/r/eM9wD0/2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to match all the stuff between an underscore _ and a backslash.

Your regex `/_(.*?)(?=\\)/g` does not really do that as it will stumble on a newline.

To actually match *anything* between an underscore and a backslash, you need a negated character class `[^\\]` - *any character but a backslash*.

Here:

```
/_([^\\]*)/g
```

This regex matches:

- `_` - matches an underscore
- `([^\\]*)` - 0 or more characters other than a backslash.

JS sample snippets:

```js
var str = 'IShouldGet3Match,allTheSequenceBetweenaUnderScoreAndASlashHeresOne:_1234_1234\\andheresAnother_1234_1234_1234\\OhLookAnotherOne!_123_12_1234567\\bahbahba';

var testPattern = /123/g;
var testResult = str.match(testPattern);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = testResult;

var pattern = /_([^\\]*)/g;
var result = str.match(pattern);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = result;

var pattern = /_([^\\]*)/g;
while ((m=pattern.exec(str)) !== null) {
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML += m[1]+"<br/>";
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Just making a basic regex works with 123:</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p>Result of actual Regex:</p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <p>Captured texts of actual Regex:</p>
    <p id="demo3"></p>
</body>
```